# Qt: Get a color name from its #RRGGBB" representation

Tags: qt

I'm writing simple "color Picker" application.
I'm using only QML

I want to know how I can convert a color #RRGGBB" representation to readable name... ?

For example: I have a rectangle within I have a text which I want to display the name of the color the rectangle is assigned with.

```
Rectangle
{
    id: rectangle
    color: "green"
    property alias myColor: rectangle.color

    // Set the size of the visual rectangle.
    // In this case the rectangle will have the same size as its parent
    anchors.fill: parent

    Text
    {
        id: colorname
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: rectangle.myColor
        color: "White"
        font.pointSize: 8
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there's an existing API for this, I don't know, but assuming there isn't: If you only need exact matches, then it's simple matter of generating a map which maps the #RRGGBB form to the color name, by iterating over list of all color names. Then you can leave colors that don't match to the hex form. But if you need to map all colors to the "closest match" color name, then you need a formula to calculate distance between two colors. I'd think google will help you find a good formula, but you probably have to implement it yourself.

Comment: if your color picker uses only defined colors this shouldn't be a problem (color picker uses only names and returns those names). In other cases there is no choice but provide some method which will perform conversion. Here is some helpful API: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#colorNames